# Conclusion from vanishing $L^2$ scalar product

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the equation

$$\int_{\mathbb R}\overline{\phi(x)}e^{iax}\psi(x+b) dx = 0, \qquad a,b \in \mathbb R$$

i.e. orthogonality of $L^2$ functions.

How can one conclude that $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x+b)$ have disjoint support?

This would then imply that $\phi\equiv 0$, since $b\in \mathbb R$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Is $\psi$ arbitrary $L_2$ function or a fixed function?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to state some information. $\psi$ is supposed to be in some closed subspace $\mathcal H_1$ that is invariant under the action of linear bounded operators on $L^2$. $\phi$ is in its orthogonal complement $\mathcal H_1^\perp$.

Comment: $\mathcal{H}_1$ is invariant under actions of any opeartor or some specific?

Comment: $\mathcal H_1$ is supposed to be invariant under the unitary Weyl operators $U(a)\psi(x)=e^{iax} \psi(x), V(b)\psi(x) = \psi(x+b), a,b\in \mathbb R$. Now it should be fully stated, sorry again. I think one can technically argue with the Fourier transform, but I am not sure how this argument works correctly.